# Get highest value of X rows

Tags: r, function, conditional-statements, xts

I'm looking for a **function to calculate the highest value for the prior X periods** on an XTS object. The function would return a vector with such values.

I would believe there are multiple ways to calculate this. Surprisingly I could not find this covered in a prior SO question. I am hoping there is a package with a function already defined for this. If there is none maybe someone knows how to tackle it.

The example below shows how the vector with the highest values of the last 3 periods would look like for XTS object XTS1.

```
library('xts')
XTS1 <- structure(c(12, 7, 7, 22, 24, 30, 26, 23, 27, 30), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "", class = c("xts", "zoo"), .CLASS = structure("double", class = "CLASS"), formattable = structure(list(formatter = "formatC", format = structure(list(format = "f", digits = 2), .Names = c("format", "digits")), preproc = "percent_preproc", postproc = "percent_postproc"), .Names = c("formatter", "format", "preproc", "postproc")), index = structure(c(1413981900, 1413982800, 1413983700, 1413984600, 1413985500, 1413986400, 1413987300, 1413988200, 1413989100, 1413990000), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(10L, 1L))

#DESIRED OUTPUT      
                     [,1]   GetHighest(3)
2014-10-22 08:45:00   12              NA
2014-10-22 09:00:00    7              12
2014-10-22 09:15:00    7              12
2014-10-22 09:30:00   22              12
2014-10-22 09:45:00   24              22
2014-10-22 10:00:00   30              24
2014-10-22 10:15:00   26              30
2014-10-22 10:30:00   23              30
2014-10-22 10:45:00   27              30
2014-10-22 11:00:00   30              27
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `rollapply` [from zoo](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/zoo/versions/1.8-0/topics/rollapply).

So it would look something like this:

```
GetHighest_3 = rollapply(data = XTS1, width = 3, FUN = max)
```

Then combine it:

```
cbind(XTS1, GetHighest_3)
```

The only probelm I see, is that it will probably return NA for the first 2 values, not only the first value, since it has a width of 3.

I wasn't able to test the code, since I don't have access to R right now, so there might be some misspelling.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That works. The NAs are not an issue. I'll lag it by 1 and get exactly what I was looking for. Spectacular.